# Direct3D 9.0 Return To The Fixed Function Pipeline

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

How does one return to the ffp after using a shader? In OpenGL you simply bind shader 0 and the same for textures, this is not made obvious in DX whether or not it is the same I can not discern.

Comment: what do you mean by return? you never leave, why return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use effects, appropriate calls to `effect->Begin()` and `effect->End()` should save and restore the pipeline state. If you use FFP before `Begin()`, this state should be restored after `End()`.

If you don't use effects, you can set null shaders. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> To set a fixed-function vertex shader (after having set a programmable vertex shader), call IDirect3DDevice9::SetVertexShader(NULL) to release the programmable shader, and then call IDirect3DDevice9::SetFVF with the fixed-function vertex format.

Comment: Thank you, so then it is just the same as OpenGL as I had presumed!